# iframe navigate to bookmark position not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firefox, iframe

there is a page in an iframe which works with angularjs http service. it loads some data and put id for each **li** in the page . so the final html page looks like this :

```
<li id="1000" ....>....</li>
<li id="1001" ....>....</li>
<li id="1002" ....>....</li>
<li id="1003" ....>....</li>
..
..
<li id="1020" ....>....</li>
```

this page is within the iframe , so i will scroll the parent iframe like below : ($scope.mid exits in li's id )

```
$q.all(promises)
....
})).then(function() {
                $("#divLoading").hide();
                var iframe = parent.document.getElementById("ConverstionsListFrame");

                iframe.location.replace(iframe.contentWindow.location + '#' + $scope.mid);
...}
```

So the code above works fine in IExplorer , but it crashes in firefox , sometime it working and sometimes no!
where is the problem ? I think maybe firefox rendering queue is different from IE which causes the iframe to not find the anchor id because it doesnot exits yet ! please take me some notes on the problem.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

This directive will solve that...

```
.directive('onLastRepeat', function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs) {
            if (scope.$last) setTimeout(function () {

                var iframe = parent.document.getElementById("ConverstionsListFrame");

                iframe.contentWindow.location.replace(iframe.contentWindow.location + '#' + scope.mid);

            }, 1);
        };
    })
```